# What can you do with System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.ExtendedRequest?

Tags: c#, active-directory

The (low level) Active Directory API [`System.DirectoryServices.Protocols`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.protocols.aspx) contains a class called [`ExtendedRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.protocols.extendedrequest.aspx). I can not seem to find any good documentation for this class but the name suggests that you can perform Active Directory operations with it that are not modeled as a standard class in this namespace.

Does anyone know what you can do with this class and how to use it? The only inputs it accepts are a string and a byte array..

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflectoring it shows that when it is used by [LdapConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.protocols.ldapconnection.aspx), it's just a wrapper for the [ldap_extended_operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366578(VS.85).aspx) API. This appears to be a common API that has documentation on several platforms. For example, [this page](http://docs.sun.com/source/817-6707/extendop.html#wp38654) shows how use it with [OID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_identifier)'s.

Answer (score 1):

Jeff's answer has given me some good hints in the right direction. The `ldap_extended_operation` API is a directory server specific API and every directory server may or may not support some set of non-standard operations. The operations a directory server supports can be found in the `rootDse` attribute `supportedExtension`.

Every supported extension has a unique OID which is the property [`ExtendedRequest.RequestName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.protocols.extendedrequest.requestname.aspx) and optionally needs data: [`ExtendedRequest.RequestValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.protocols.extendedrequest.requestvalue.aspx). What data you should provide for what request can probably be found somewhere in the documentation for the active directory server.